# adding a recaptcha to the form

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

I have been trying to add reCaptcha verifications from google, the problem is that after trying to send it moves me directly to form.php, in domain / form.php, and the message is not sent.
Below I am sending the code, thank you in advance for help in solving the problem

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $secret = '6LclC3QUAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5hrAxfHXXXiMH';
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
    $result = json_decode($url, TRUE);
    if ($result['success'] == 1) {

        $to = 'XXX@mail.com'; // Put in your email address here
        $subject  = "Nowe zlecenie"; // The default subject. Will appear by default in all messages. Change this if you want.

        // User info (DO NOT EDIT!)
        $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']); // sender's name
        $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['mail1']); // sender's email
        $servicetype = stripslashes($_REQUEST['service-type']);
        $vehicalmake = stripslashes($_REQUEST['vehical-make']);
        $vehicalmodel = stripslashes($_REQUEST['vehical-model']);
        $appointmentdate = stripslashes($_REQUEST['appointment-date']);
        $appointmenttime = stripslashes($_REQUEST['appointment-time']);
        $phone = stripslashes($_REQUEST['phone']);
        $message = stripslashes($_REQUEST['message']);
        $mail1 = stripslashes($_REQUEST['mail1']); // sender's email
        $msg = "";

        // The message you will receive in your mailbox
        // Each parts are commented to help you understand what it does exaclty.
        // YOU DON'T NEED TO EDIT IT BELOW BUT IF YOU DO, DO IT WITH CAUTION!
        $msg .= "Imie i nazwisko : ".$name."\r\n\n";  // add sender's name to the message
        $msg .= "Adres e-mail: ".$mail1."\r\n\n";  // add sender's email to the message
        $msg .= "Numer telefonu: ".$phone."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Rodzaj uslugi: ".$servicetype."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Typ nadwozia: ".$vehicalmake."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Model auta: ".$vehicalmodel."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Data wykonania: ".$appointmentdate."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Godzina: ".$appointmenttime."\r\n\n";  // add sender's sources to the message
        $msg .= "Wiadomosc od kupujacego: ".$message."\r\n\n";  // add sender's checkboxes to the message
        $msg .= "\r\n\n";
        $mail = mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:");

        if($mail) {
            header("Location:index.html"); 
            echo 'send';
        } else {
            echo 'Message could not be sent!';
        }

    }else{
      echo 'infooo';
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Can I suggest you start by reading the [Google recaptcha examples and documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `file_get_contents` that defaults to `GET` and the Recaptcha API [only allows `POST` requests](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request).

You just need to change your code to make a `POST` request:

```
$secret = '6LclC3QUAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5hrAxfHXXXiMH';
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = array(
            'secret' => $secret,
            'response' => $response,
            'remoteip' => $remoteip
);
$options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$res = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context), true);
```

Comment: Your answer is off. Where did OP use a get request?